# Logstash date parsing as timestamp using the date filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Well, after looking around quite a lot, I could not find a solution to my problem, as it "should" work, but obviously doesn't.
I'm using on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine Logstash 1.4.2-1-2-2c0f5a1, and I am receiving messages such as the following one:

```
2014-08-05 10:21:13,618 [17] INFO  Class.Type - This is a log message from the class:
  BTW, I am also multiline
```

In the input configuration, I do have a `multiline` codec and the event is parsed correctly. I also separate the event text in several parts so that it is easier to read.

In the end, I obtain, as seen in Kibana, something like the following (JSON view):

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2014.08.06",
  "_type": "customType",
  "_id": "PRtj-EiUTZK3HWAm5RiMwA",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2014-08-06T08:51:21.160Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "tags": [
      "multiline"
    ],
    "type": "utg-su",
    "host": "ubuntu-14",
    "path": "/mnt/folder/thisIsTheLogFile.log",
    "logTimestamp": "2014-08-05;10:21:13.618",
    "logThreadId": "17",
    "logLevel": "INFO",
    "logMessage": "Class.Type - This is a log message from the class:\r\n  BTW, I am also multiline\r"
  },
  "sort": [
    "21",
    1407315081160
  ]
}
```

You may have noticed that I put a ";" in the timestamp. The reason is that I want to be able to sort the logs using the timestamp string, and apparently logstash is not that good at that (e.g.: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html).

I have unsuccessfull tried to use the `date` filter in multiple ways, and it apparently did not work.

```
date {
            locale => "en"
            match => ["logTimestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS", "ISO8601"]
            timezone => "Europe/Vienna"
            target => "@timestamp"
            add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
        }
```

Since I read that the Joda library *may* have problems if the string is not strictly ISO 8601-compliant (very picky and expects a T, see https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-180), I also tried to use `mutate` to convert the string to something like `2014-08-05T10:21:13.618` and then use `"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"`. That also did not work.

I do not want to have to manually put a +02:00 on the time because that would give problems with daylight saving.

In any of these cases, the event goes to elasticsearch, but `date` does apparently nothing, as `@timestamp` and `logTimestamp` are different and no `debug` field is added.

Any idea how I could make the logTime strings properly sortable? I focused on converting them to a proper timestamp, but any other solution would also be welcome.

As you can see below:
[image: Sorting with timestamps: OK]

When sorting over `@timestamp`, elasticsearch can do it properly, but since this is not the "real" log timestamp, but rather when the logstash event was read, I need (obviously) to be able to sort also over `logTimestamp`. This is what then is output. Obviously not that useful:

[image: Sorting with string: Not OK. Any suggestions?]

Any help is welcome! Just let me know if I forgot some information that may be useful.

**Update:**

Here is the filter config file that finally worked:

```
# Filters messages like this:
# 2014-08-05 10:21:13,618 [17] INFO  Class.Type - This is a log message from the class:
#  BTW, I am also multiline

# Take only type- events (type-componentA, type-componentB, etc)
filter {
    # You cannot write an "if" outside of the filter!
    if "type-" in [type] {
        grok {
            # Parse timestamp data. We need the "(?m)" so that grok (Oniguruma internally) correctly parses multi-line events
            patterns_dir => "./patterns"
            match => [ "message", "(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTimestampString}[ ;]\[%{DATA:logThreadId}\][ ;]%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}[ ;]*%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}" ]
        }

        # The timestamp may have commas instead of dots. Convert so as to store everything in the same way
        mutate {
            gsub => [
                # replace all commas with dots
                "logTimestampString", ",", "."
                ]
        }

        mutate {
            gsub => [
                # make the logTimestamp sortable. With a space, it is not! This does not work that well, in the end
                # but somehow apparently makes things easier for the date filter
                "logTimestampString", " ", ";"
                ]
        }

        date {
            locale => "en"
            match => ["logTimestampString", "YYYY-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
            timezone => "Europe/Vienna"
            target => "logTimestamp"
        }
    }
}

filter {
    if "type-" in [type] {
        # Remove already-parsed data
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "message" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for posting the working result, with Ben's response and yours made my issue trivial!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have tested your `date` filter. it works on me!

Here is my configuration

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {
    date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["message", "YYYY-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
        timezone => "Europe/Vienna"
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
   }
}

output {
    stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

And I use this input:

```
2014-08-01;11:00:22.123
```

The output is:

```
{
   "message" => "2014-08-01;11:00:22.123",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-08-01T09:00:22.123Z",
      "host" => "ABCDE",
     "debug" => "timestampMatched"
}
```

So, please make sure that your `logTimestamp` has the correct value. 
It is probably other problem. Or can you provide your log event and logstash configuration for more discussion. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of trying it on `stdin` and damn on me for not having though of that! With that I started playing around with the filter ordering (inside the same `if` or not, among other things) and came up with a configuration that worked :) Thanks for your help! I will also put up the config in case it is useful for someone.

Comment: Somehow I have problem when following this solution because of linebreak. I got error like \"2014-08-01;11:00:22.123 \r\" is malformed at \" \r\""

To solve this, I follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122555/how-to-remove-trailing-newline-from-message-field

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - with a slightly different datetime format:

```
# 2017-11-22 13:00:01,621 INFO [AtlassianEvent::0-BAM::EVENTS:pool-2-thread-2] [BuildQueueManagerImpl] Sent ExecutableQueueUpdate: addToQueue, agents known to be affected: []
input {
   file {
       path => "/data/atlassian-bamboo.log"
       start_position => "beginning"
       type => "logs"      
       codec => multiline {
                pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
                charset => "ISO-8859-1"
                negate => true
                what => "previous"                
       }       
   }
}
filter {
   grok {
      match => [ "message", "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread_id}\]%{SPACE}\[%{WORD:classname}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" ]
   }

    date {
        match => ["logtime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS Z", "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a" ]
        timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
   }   
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```