# Logstash - not able to get the @timestamp to work

Tags: timestamp, logstash

Logstash noob here, I am trying to get these log lines filtered through logstash.

```
2015-03-31 02:53:39 INFO  This is info message 5
```

The config file that I am using is this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/sample/log4j_log.log"
    start_position => beginning
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message" , "%{DATESTAMP:logtimestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" ]
  }

  date {
    locale => "en"
    match => [ "logtimestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}

output {
  #elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The output I get is

```
         "message" => "2015-03-31 02:53:39 INFO  This is info message 5",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "0015-03-30T21:00:11.000Z",
            "host" => "abc",
            "path" => "/sample/log4j_log.log",
    "logtimestamp" => "15-03-31 02:53:39",
           "level" => "INFO",
             "msg" => " This is info message 5"
```

I see that the logtimestamp field is showing the format as "YY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", I am not sure why it is getting converted tot his format, and I even tried that in the date filter.
IN those cases I get this output.

```
{
         "message" => "2015-03-31 02:53:39 INFO  This is info message 5",
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2015-04-07T17:55:51.231Z",
            "host" => "abc",
            "path" => "/sample/log4j_log.log",
    "logtimestamp" => "15-03-31 02:53:39",
           "level" => "INFO",
             "msg" => " This is info message 5"
}
```

In all of this the @timestamp is not matching up with the actual log event timestamp and this causes problems for elastic search + kibana visualization.

I have tried to include target => "@timestamp", locale => "en" as suggested by other questions on StackOverflow with no success.

The only thing I seem to not have tried is :
[Logstash date parsing as timestamp using the date filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156517/logstash-date-parsing-as-timestamp-using-the-date-filter)
Which i dont believe is fully applicable to my log event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You grok pattern is incorrect.

Please change to this, Use `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601` instead of `DATESTAMP`

```
grok {
    match => [ "message" , "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtimestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" ]
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{
     "message" => "2015-03-31 02:53:39 INFO  This is info message 5",
    "@version" => "1",
  "@timestamp" => "2015-03-30T18:53:39.000Z",
        "host" => "BEN_LIM",
"logtimestamp" => "2015-03-31 02:53:39",
       "level" => "INFO",
         "msg" => " This is info message 5"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A quick question, the timestamp has moved to 18hrs, I believe that is on account of the timezone differences, so the question is, does logstash infer the current timestamp from the system it is running on?

Comment: Ignore the above commend, LogStash does infer the timezone of the machine running the logstash process and uses that to convert the timestamp data to UTC.

Comment: Yes, Logstash will convert it to UTC time, I am in +08:00 timezone area. :P