# Parsing a date field in logstash to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to parse log files from IIS to the ELK stack (Logstash:2.3, Elastic:2.3 and Kibana:4.5, CentOS 7 vm).

I have attempted to parse a date field from the log message as the event timestamp using the date filter below in my logstash configuration:

```
date {
    match => ["date_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "Europe/London"
    locale => "en"
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

The first few characters of the entire log message that was parsed to Elastic Search is:

```
"message": "2016-03-01 03:30:49  .........
```

The date field above was parsed to Elastic Search as:

```
"date_timestamp": "16-03-01 03:30:49",
```

However, the event timestamp that was parsed to Elastic Search using the date filter above is:

```
"@timestamp": "0016-03-01T03:32:04.000Z",
```

I will like the @timestamp to be exactly 2016-03-01T03:30:49 as I can't immediately figure out why there is a difference between the hours and minutes.

I have looked at similar problems and documentations such as [this one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156517/logstash-date-parsing-as-timestamp-using-the-date-filter) and this one on [logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target) and [logstash documentation.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target)

Any pointer in the right direction will be appreciated.

Regards

SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `date_timestamp`  you have only 2 characters for year:  "**16**-03-01 03:30:49", so the date pattern in  your  `date` filter is incorrect, should be:

```
date {
    match => ["date_timestamp", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "Europe/London"
    locale => "en"
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response - however, the original message that was parsed to elastic search is this: "message": "2016-03-01 03:30:49  ......... - the "16-03-01 03:30:49" should have been 2016-03-01 03:30:49 - isn't it?

Comment: your suggestion works - thanks.  I did not previously figure that that the format is that of the parsed field and not format of the original message.   In the absence of any other answer, I will mark this as accepted because it works for me. Cheers  - SO.