# Filter on a nested date field in logstash

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to use date filter on a nested date field in json

json snippet:

```
"_source": {
      "QueryResult": {
        "Results": [
          {
            "CreationDate": "2016-12-13T05:37:11.953Z",
```

filter config:

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "[QueryResult][Results][CreationDate]", "ISO8601" ]
  }
}
```

It keeps failing with below error:

```
    [2017-01-05T19:40:44,575][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash. {"exception"=>java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CreationDate", "backtrace"=>["java.lang.
NumberFormatException.forInputString(java/lang/NumberFormatException.java:65)", "java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java/lang/Integer.java:580)", "java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java/lang/Integer.java:615)", "org.logstash.Accessors.fetch(org/logstash/Accessors.java:130)", "org.logstash.Accessors.get(org/logstas
h/Accessors.java:20)", "org.logstash.Event.getUnconvertedField(org/logstash/Event.java:160)", "org.logstash.Event.getField(org/logstash/Event.java:150)", "org.logstash.filters.DateFilter.executeParsers(org/logstash/filters/DateFilter.java:97)", "org.logstash.filters.DateFilter.receive(org/logstash/f
ilters/DateFilter.java:78)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:497)", "RUBY.multi_filter(/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-date-3.1.1/lib/logstash/filters/date.rb:191)", "RUBY.multi_filter(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filt
er_delegator.rb:41)", "RUBY.filter_func((eval):42)", "LogStash::Pipeline.filter_batch(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:295)", "LogStash::Pipeline.filter_batch(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:295)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:
281)", "LogStash::Util::WrappedSynchronousQueue::ReadBatch.each(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:192)", "LogStash::Util::WrappedSynchronousQueue::ReadBatch.each(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:192)", "or
g.jruby.RubyHash.each(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342)", "LogStash::Util::WrappedSynchronousQueue::ReadBatch.each(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:191)", "LogStash::Util::WrappedSynchronousQueue::ReadBatch.each(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logsta
sh/util/wrapped_synchronous_queue.rb:191)", "LogStash::Pipeline.filter_batch(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:294)", "LogStash::Pipeline.filter_batch(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:294)", "RUBY.worker_loop(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/lo
gstash/pipeline.rb:282)", "RUBY.start_workers(/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:258)", "java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)"]}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for few days now, but no luck.

I tried removing the codec: json as suggested @ [Access nested JSON Field in Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500149/access-nested-json-field-in-logstash) and checked the date format as suggested @ [0 Parsing a date field in logstash to elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619758/parsing-a-date-field-in-logstash-to-elastic-search) and [Nested field access in date filter](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/OxVOCebWm2c)

Based on above post, I tried below filter snippet, but still got the same error:

```
     date {
        match => [ "[QueryResult][Results][CreationDate]", 
                "UNIX",
                "UNIX_MS",
                "ISO8601",
                "timestamp",
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS",
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",
                "MMM  d HH:mm:ss",
                "MMM dd HH:mm:ss",
                "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z",
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
                "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z" ]
        target => "timestamp"
      }
```

Any help/clue will be appreciated.

Comment: The complaint is "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CreationDate", which means it's trying to find your data format in the string "CreationDate", *not* the string you're expecting it to search.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alain. So I'm probably using the wrong expression to match the date value. Any suggestion on what should be the first expression, to match the date value of CreationDate?

Comment: as a workaround you could probably use a mutate filter to simply copy the nested field to a field at the top level of the doc and then date filter that, I'll see if I can reproduce your issue and find a real solution though

Comment: Another thing I noticed that may be relevant is that Results is an array with  an object at index 0 that has a CreationDate. Try using `[QueryResult][Results][0][CreationDate]`

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do is use the CreationDate as @timstamp for the list/array of Results. So that when the output is written to easticsearch the timestamp is not the index creation date but the date in CreationDate field

Comment: As in each item in the Results array will be a different document in Elasticsearch?