# Logstash - Custom Timestamp Error

Tags: date, timestamp, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to input a timestamp field in Logstash and i am getting dateparsefailure message.

My Message -

2014-08-01;11:00:22.123

Pipeline file

```
input {
stdin{}
#beats {
#        port => "5043"
#    }
}
# optional.
filter {
  date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["message", "YYYY-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
   }
 }
output {
elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "127.0.0.1:9200" ]
    }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Can someone tell me what i am missing ?

**Update 1**

I referred to the link - [How to remove trailing newline from message field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122555/how-to-remove-trailing-newline-from-message-field) and now it works.

But, in my log message, i have multiple values other than timestamp

```
<B 2014-08-01;11:00:22.123 Field1=Value1 Field2=Value2
```

When i give this as input, it is not working. How to read a part of the log and make it as timestamp ?

**Update 2**

it works now.

Changed the config file as below

```
filter {
kv
   {

   }
 mutate {
    strip => "message"
  }
  date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["timestamp1", "YYYY-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
        target => "@timestamp"
        add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the answer below and steps i used to solve the issue so that i can help people like me.

Step 1 - I read the message in the form of key and value pair

Step 2 - I trimmed off the extra space that leads to parse exception

Step 3 - I read the timestamp value and other fields in respective fields.

```
input {
beats {
        port => "5043"
    }
}
# optional.
filter {
  kv { }
  date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
            remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
        }
}
output {
elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "127.0.0.1:9200" ]
    }
}
```